# iptables: BLOCK all general OUTPUT on PC (no server)

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I'm trying

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

However, everything on the internet seems to require `-P OUTPUT ACCEPT`. Otherwise nothing would work.

Also `--state NEW` in fir INPUT required if you don't want to tun a server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what are you trying to do, but if you want to allow only access to TCP port 80 on the Internet, this worked for me:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You may also want to allow port 53 if using some name server, otherwise your browser won't resolve any domain names.

Comment: Ah, it might be the nameserver! Will try this now. Also, I want to allow https, so port 443

Comment: Oh, no, allowing port 53 for OUTPUT didn't solve it.

Comment: You're not using a proxy server, are you? If you do, then you also have to allow connections to the proxy server's port.

Comment: Also, try allowing UDP port 53 for DNS. Some systems use UDP instead of TCP.